# 12.04 - network manager not started at boot

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, fresh install. I have a wired connection (eth1 interface), the IP address is assigned by DHCP, and PEAP authentication (wpa_supplicant) is set up.

My problem is that network does not start at boot. I have to log in without internet connection, and then I have to start network-manager manually (sudo start network-manager). It works, the connection starts and I am online.

So my problem is why network manager does not start at boot? In /var/log/syslog I found the following messages:

```
init: network-interface (lo) pre-start process (589) terminated with status 1
init: network-interface (eth1) pre-start process (590) terminated with status 1
init: network-interface (lo) post-stop process (604) terminated with status 1
init: network-interface (eth1) post-stop process (606) terminated with status 1
```

and a bit further

```
init: networking main process (873) terminated with status 1
```

I am new to Ubuntu, I tried to find a solution by myself, but I totally failed. Please, can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an error in you interface config script.
Take a look at `/etc/network/interfaces` keep it simple, network-manager will manage the interface.

Bellow you have an example of a working configuration. Just the first line will be enough, but try adding the last two if you'd like.

```
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```